# Defining a function with For loop within For loop

Tags: functions

```
h[n_] := For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
   For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, 
    g = g + i*j]; f = f + g;];
h[10]
```

I want to define a function to calculate the Sum from i to n from the Sum of j to n of i*j

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are asking for this?

```
h[n_] := Block[{i, j, g, f},
  f = 0;
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
   g = 0;
   For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, g = g + i*j];
   f = f + g;
   ];
  f
  ]
```

However, easier and more efficient ways would be

```
h[n_] := Sum[i j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
```

or

```
h[n_] := Total[Range[1, n]]^2
```

or

```
h[n_] := (n (n + 1)/2)^2
```